# bash creating a csv file

Tags: bash, csv

I would like to create a csv file. The filename of the .txt file should be the header and all jpgs files inside the .txt file should be the rows.

Example:

```
filename1.txt, filename2.txt, filename3.txt
filename1a.jpg,filename2a.jpg,filename3a.jpg
filename1b.jpg,filename2b.jpg,filename3b.jpg
filename1c.jpg,filename2c.jpg,filename3c.jpg
              ,filename2d.jpg,
```

The problem I am having is how to append to file with the right format as above?

```
for f in $(ls *.txt) do
    csv_header="$f"
    #get all jpgs in current txt file
    array_jpgs=( $(get_jpgs "$f") )
    for jpg in "${array_jpgs[@]}" do
        #printf "%s," "$csv_header" >> "$CSV_FILE"
    done
done
```

I am using GNU bash, version 4.3.33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `paste` to combine a bunch of temporary files. (Assuming the output of `get_jpgs` is one file name per line.)

```
for f in *.txt; do   # Do not parse ls
    { printf '%s\n' "$f"
      get_jpgs "$f"
    } > "$f.tmp"
done
paste -d, *.tmp > "$CSV_FILE"
rm *.tmp
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know about paste.